# Traverse UP the DOM to select label wrapped in radio button input (Drupal exposed filters)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm using an exposed filter radio button in Drupal and i'm noticing that the html structure is making it difficult to select the label to change upon being :checked.

If the html structure was input first, then label, I'd have no problem selecting the label with "input[type=radio]:checked + label" but, the labels wrapping around the input.

```js
if (jQuery("input[type=radio]:checked")){
 jQuery("input[type=radio]:checked .control-label").css("font-weight", "bold");
}
```

```html
<body>
<label class="control-label" for="edit-tid-all">
  <input class="bef-select-as-radios form-radio" type="radio" id="edit-tid-all" name="tid" value="All" checked="checked" style="font-weight: bold;">
  Select all 
</label>
  <label class="control-label" for="edit-tid-all">
  <input class="bef-select-as-radios form-radio" type="radio" id="edit-tid-all" name="tid" value="All" checked="checked" style="font-weight: bold;">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
  Selection 1 
</label>
  <label class="control-label" for="edit-tid-all">
  <input class="bef-select-as-radios form-radio" type="radio" id="edit-tid-all" name="tid" value="All" checked="checked" style="font-weight: bold;">
  Selection 2 
</label>
```

I can see that it's adding the font-weight bold to the input field, and that's not what I want. I want it on the checked label only. Any ideas?

Comment: Your logic is flawed as the `if` statement is coercing a jQuery object to a boolean, which will always result in `true`. What event are you running this code under?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, honestly, I don't know. it's a better exposed filter radio button within drupal. I don't think there are any events for the radio buttons.

Comment: Ok then a better question would be, what are you trying to achieve? I assume you want to make the label next to the chosen radio button bold, is that right?

Comment: yes, bold label depending on if it's checked or not. The way drupal has the label wrapped around the input makes me think the structure is wrong.

Comment: Nope, nothing wrong with the label structure at all. I added an answer for you below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you want to make the label closest to the selected radio bold when chosen then you need to add an event handler to the input itself. You can then get the `label` using `closest()` before adding the class. Also note that you'll need to remove the class from the other labels too. Try this:

```js
$('.bef-select-as-radios').change(function() {
  $('label').removeClass('active');
  $(this).closest('label').addClass('active');
}).filter(':checked').change();
```

```css
label.active {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label class="control-label">
  <input class="bef-select-as-radios form-radio" type="radio" name="tid" value="All" checked="true" />
  Select all 
</label>
<label class="control-label">
  <input class="bef-select-as-radios form-radio" type="radio" name="tid" value="All" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
  Selection 1 
</label>
<label class="control-label">
  <input class="bef-select-as-radios form-radio" type="radio" name="tid" value="All" />
  Selection 2 
</label>
```

One thing to note here is that I removed the `id` attributes from the inputs as they were all identical, when they must be unique. This can cause some unexpected behaviour so I simply removed them.

Comment: The id's were because of my copy paste from console code. They actually have different id's on the site itself. I'll give it a try on the site.

Comment: I think I have too many other things going on for this to work. So I'll keep trying but I get the gist of it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way to do this. I had some help with this one.

```
jQuery("input[name=tid]").on("change", function(e){
      jQuery("#edit-tid").find("label").css("font-weight", "normal");
      jQuery(this).closest("label").css("font-weight", "bold")
});
```

Works like a charm!